# Can I create a top level menu in a Google Slides add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, add-on, google-slides

We are developing a Google Slides add-on and we need to add some custom top-level menus. The documentation on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus says:

> Scripts that are published as add-ons for Google Sheets, Docs, or Forms cannot create top-level custom menus.

But when I installed the publicly available [Poll Everywhere for Google Slides](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/poll-everywhere-for-googl/jeehnidbmlhpkncbplipfalpjkhlokaa) add-on, it added the Poll Everywhere menu as a top-level menu for all documents. How could that be possible considering the quote above?

[image: Poll Everywhere top-level menu]

Answer (score 0):

[Poll Everywhere for Google Slides](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/poll-everywhere-for-googl/jeehnidbmlhpkncbplipfalpjkhlokaa) is not an Apps Script add-on, it's a Chrome extension.

[image]

Related

- [Apps Script vs Chrome Extension: Writing an alternative spellchecker to Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26484751/1595451)